# bad bitmap error when setting Uri

Tags: android

I would like to make an ImageView display an image on a website. So I create a new ImageView and execute `imgView.setImageURI(uri);`

When I launch the app the image does not appear and I get the error, "resolveUri failed on bad Bitmap Uri (uri)".

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to download the image and then set it as bitmap.
Here is one of the many examples:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

Answer (score 27):

If it's not a content URI, [this link](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/8eea6c95a78012ea/) may help. It seems to indicate that `imgView.setImageURI()` should not be used for regular URIs. Copying in the relevant bit:

> Yes, `ImageView.setImageURI(ContentURI uri)` works, but it is for content URIs particular to the Android platform, not URIs specifying Internet resources. The convention is applied to binary objects (images, for example) which cannot be exposed directly through a ContentProvider's Cursor methods. Instead, a String reference is used to reference a distinct content URI, which can be resolved by a separate query against the content provider. The setImageURI method is simply a wrapper to perform those steps for you.
>
> I have tested this usage of `setImageView`, and it does work as expected. For your usage, though, I'd look at `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()` and `URL.openStream()`.

Also to make this answer self-contained, the sample code from another post at that link, showing how to do it:

```
private Bitmap getImageBitmap(String url) {
    Bitmap bm = null;
    try {
        URL aURL = new URL(url);
        URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
        bis.close();
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error getting bitmap", e);
    }
    return bm;
}
```

I haven't tested this code, I'm just paranoid and like to ensure SO answers are useful even if every other site on the net disappears :-)

Comment: Is the following code also necessary?
`val policy = ThreadPolicy.Builder (). permitAll (). build ()
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy (policy)`

Comment: But I have this error : android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: @Gank, since your error is vastly different from the one in this question, you should probably ask a *different* question.

Answer (score 8):

[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) is an awesome library for displaying images!

```
 Glide.with(context)
                    .load(uri)
                    .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 3):

> Use library Picasso
>
> Manifest

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"

> build gradle

implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

> Activity:

Picasso.get().load(photoUrl).into(imageView);

Answer (score 0):

First, you should download the image and save it in your `device(sdcard or memory)`.
Then, get its file path, using `Uri.parse(filePath)` to convert path to uri
finally, call `ImageView`'s `setImageURI(Uri)` to fullfill.
-- I use this way to achieve my purpose and there is a bug:if the image is to large(maybe exceed 1Mb or so, it may report outOfMemeroy Exception!!!)